# Sorted List in Coq

Tags: sorting, coq

I define a sorted list as follows:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive SortedList : list nat -> Prop :=
| sort0 : SortedList []
| sort1 : forall a, SortedList [a]
| sort2 : forall z1 z2 l, z1 <= z2 -> SortedList (z2 :: l) -> SortedList (z1 :: z2 :: l).
```

And I think the following theorem is correct.

```
Theorem SortedList_sep:
  forall l1 l2,
  SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l1 /\ SortedList l2.
```

But I cannot prove this theorem. Can anyone give me some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  I tried to keep it simple to step through.

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.


Inductive SortedList : list nat -> Prop :=
| sort0 : SortedList []
| sort1 : forall a, SortedList [a]
| sort2 : forall z1 z2, forall l, z1 <= z2 -> SortedList (z2 :: l) -> SortedList (z1 :: z2 :: l).


Theorem SortedList_sep1:
  forall l1 l2,
  SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l1.
Proof.
  induction l1;
    firstorder.
  - now constructor.
  - destruct l1.
    now  constructor.
    rewrite <- ?app_comm_cons in *.
    inversion H.
    constructor.
    + now trivial.
    + apply IHl1 with l2.
      rewrite <- ?app_comm_cons in *.
      now trivial.
Qed.

Theorem SortedList_sep2:
  forall l1 l2,
    SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l2.
Proof.
  induction l1;
    firstorder.
  rewrite <- app_comm_cons in *.
  inversion H.
  - apply IHl1.
    rewrite <- H2.
    now constructor.
  - apply IHl1.
    rewrite H1 in H3.
    now apply H3.
Qed.

Theorem SortedList_sep:
  forall l1 l2,
  SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l1 /\ SortedList l2.
Proof.
  firstorder.
  now apply SortedList_sep1 with l2.
  now apply SortedList_sep2 with l1.
Qed.
```

and here is a 'code golfed' version, which is shorter, but less "grokkable".

```
Theorem SortedList_sep:
  forall l1 l2,
  SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l1 /\ SortedList l2.
Proof.
  induction l1; firstorder; try destruct l1; inversion H;
    rewrite <- ?app_comm_cons in *; try constructor; firstorder.
Qed.
```

Comment: Code-golfing a bit more: `Theorem SortedList_sep l1 l2 : SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l1 /\ SortedList l2.
Proof. now induction l1 as [|?[|]]; inversion 1; intuition constructor. Qed.`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do the proof is using induction on `l1` because the operation `++` is defined by recursion on its first argument. Another option is to do induction on the term of type `SortedList (l1 ++ l2)` in the context, that would require a bit more context & goal management (e.g. generalization, etc.) and also it seems that you'd need several destructions on `l1` anyways.

@larsr's answer shows one approach to the problem. Here is a "combined" approach where we prove the original theorem with conjunction:

```
Theorem SortedList_sep l1 l2 :
  SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l1 /\ SortedList l2.
Proof.
  induction l1 as [|h1 l1 IH]; simpl; intros H.
  - split; [constructor | assumption].
  - inversion H; subst.
    + apply eq_sym, app_eq_nil in H2 as [->->].
      split; constructor.
    + destruct l1 as [|h2 l1]; simpl in * |-.
      * subst l2; split; [constructor | assumption].
      * inversion H1; subst. apply IH in H3 as [? ?].
        split; [now constructor | assumption].
Qed.
```

Now we can easily define special cases like `SortedList_sep1`:

```
Theorem SortedList_sep1 l1 l2 :
  SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l1.
Proof. apply SortedList_sep. Qed.

Theorem SortedList_sep2 l1 l2 :
  SortedList (l1 ++ l2) -> SortedList l2.
Proof. apply SortedList_sep. Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me also suggest a solution using the mathematical components library:

```
Theorem SortedList_sep l1 l2 :
  sorted leq (l1 ++ l2) ->
  sorted leq l1 /\ sorted leq l2.
Proof.
rewrite -(path_min_sorted (x:=0)) // cat_path => /andP[h1 h2].
by have/allP h := order_path_min leq_trans h2; rewrite !path_min_sorted in h1 h2.
Qed.
```

I guess the proof style can be improved but that's an exercise for the reader.

**Edit:** Anton Trunov proposes this nicer proof, which is the "right" one:

```
Proof.
by move/(subseq_sorted leq_trans)=> h; rewrite !h ?suffix_subseq ?prefix_subseq.
Qed.
```

Note that contrary to other solutions, none of the above proofs use induction directly, but they are based on more general lemmas. This is much preferred, as it reflects the reasoning a "real" mathematician would do. Concretely, the "right" proof states: "a subsequence of an ordered sequence is ordered", which IMO is the right intuition in this case.

Comment: Here is an alternative proof: `by move=> S; split; apply: (subseq_sorted leq_trans _ S);
   [apply: prefix_subseq | apply: suffix_subseq].`

Comment: Perhaps it would make the reader's life a bit easier if the imports had been added to the post -- `From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrbool.
From mathcomp Require Import ssrnat seq path.`

Comment: Good one! I may suggest tho a use of `rewrite` as a more idiomatic solution: `by move/(subseq_sorted leq_trans)=> hs; rewrite !hs ?(suffix_subseq,prefix_subseq).` Sadly, it is still over the limit by 1 character :(

Comment: Very nice! Btw, `?suffix_subseq ?prefix_subseq` instead of `?(suffix_subseq,prefix_subseq)` resolves the one-character issue :)

Comment: Ahhh I need to learn how to count, indeed the optimal for is `!(h,suffix_subseq,prefix_subseq)` or [with a `?`], however it is far slower so I think the one above is preferred.